# Wave Equation for a free particle and its uncertainty

Tags: wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

As a general description of a free particle the wave equation may be written as so:

$$\psi (x,t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \hslash}}\int{dp\phi (p)e^{i[px-(p^2/2m)t]/\hslash}}$$

When the initial condition of $\psi (x,0)$ is given we can find all the other values at other times.
Here it is evident that there is no uncertainty but I couldn't clearly understand why that is the case. Is the wave function crashing when we do this operation so that the probability of one of the state becomes evident? Or is this a special case or an out-dated equation? What am I missing here?

Comment: What does "this operation" refer to? Does the term "crashing" mean "collapsing"?

Comment: @flippiefanus I am sorry for the confusion. This operation refers to the state t=0. Crashing means collapsing.

Comment: A delta function is the only wavefunction with no uncertainty.